# casperjs scrape giving empty webpage response

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

I have written a script for CasperJS which is supposed to read a json file which has a list of sites with details on how to log into, and run the search pages for each keyword.

I have tested my code with one site which worked, however for the second site, it logs in but when it attempts to goto a search page it returns an empty page.

This is my casper setup:

```
casper = require('casper').create(
  clientScripts: [
    'jquery.min.js'
  ]
  verbose: true
  logLevel: "debug"
)
```

This is the loop code:

```
casper.start().each sites, (self, site)->
  search_results[site.title] = {}
  self.thenOpen site.login.path, 
    method: "get"
    data: site.login.getdata
  , ->
    @echo "Visiting Login Page: #{site.login.path}"
  self.then ->
  self.then ->
    @evaluate (ufield,user,pfield,pass)->
      jQuery(ufield).val(user)
      jQuery(pfield).val(pass)
    ,
      ufield: site.login.form.username.element
      user: site.login.form.username.value
      pfield: site.login.form.password.element
      pass: site.login.form.password.value
  self.then ->
    @echo "Added formdata" 
  self.then ->
    @click "#{site.login.form.element} #{site.login.form.submit}"
  self.then ->
    @echo "Submitted form" 
  self.then ->  
    @waitUntilVisible site.login.form.wait.element, ->
      @echo 'Page Loaded'
    , ->
      @echo "Login Failed"
      @exit 1
    , max_timeout
  self.each keys, (self, skey)->
    self.thenOpen site.search.path, 
      method: "get"
      data: site.login.getdata
    , ->
      @echo "Visiting Search Page: #{site.search.path}, for #{skey}"
    self.then ->
      @echo @page.content
      @waitUntilVisible "#{site.search.form.element} #{site.search.form.query.element}"
      , ->
        @echo "Search Form Visible"
      , ->
        @echo "Search Visit Failed"
        @exit 1
      , max_timeout
    self.then ->
      @evaluate (key, feild)->
        jQuery(feild).val(key)
      ,
        key: skey
        feild: site.search.form.query.element
    self.then ->
      @echo "Added searchdata"
    self.then ->
      @click "#{site.search.form.element} #{site.search.form.submit}"
    self.then ->
      @echo "Submited Search"
    self.then ->
      @waitUntilVisible site.search.form.wait.element
      , ->
        @echo "Search Results Visible"
      , ->
        @echo "Search Failed"
        @exit 1
      , max_timeout
    self.then ->
      result_links = @evaluate (linktag)->
        res = []
        res_els = __utils__.findAll(linktag)
        Array.prototype.forEach.call res_els, (e)->
          href = e.getAttribute("href")
          label = jQuery(e).text()
          res.push {href: href, label: label} if href?
        res
      ,
        linktag: "#{site.search.threads.element} #{site.search.threads.link.element}"
    self.then ->
      utils.dump result_links
      search_results[site.title][skey] = result_links
```

Console output to do with the fail is as follows:

```
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://www.cyclingforums.com, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.cyclingforums.com/, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.cyclingforums.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected jquery.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 50/68 http://www.cyclingforums.com/ (HTTP 200)
Visiting Search Page: http://www.cyclingforums.com, for track
[info] [phantom] Step 50/68: done in 63268ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 51/68 http://www.cyclingforums.com/ (HTTP 200)
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
[info] [phantom] Step 51/68: done in 63352ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 52/69 http://www.cyclingforums.com/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step 52/69: done in 63452ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
Search Visit Failed
```

Why is the page responding with an empty page?

EDIT: Through testing with other sites, it seems that the base code works, but this one site seems to be causing issues.

Comment: It could be that the site has an invalid ssl cert try running `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes {otherthings}` if you've not already. It may also be that the site in question has frames that are interfering you can check with `window.top.frames.length`. And if there are frames you'll probably want to iterate through them.